# Not able to connect oracle cloud (TNS: protocol adapter error)

Tags: oracle, oracle-cloud-infrastructure, oracleclient

I have done below steps:

I have copied the sqlnet.ora file content from cloud wallet and added it into my local sqlnet.ora. Also did for tnsnames.ora file and added the cloud wallet location.

---

```
# sqlnet.ora Network Configuration File: 
C:\app\Learncode\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\sqlnet.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

# This file is actually generated by netca. But if customers choose to
# install "Software Only", this file wont exist and without the native
# authentication, they will not be able to connect to the database on NT.

SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (NTS)

NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (TNSNAMES, EZCONNECT)

#for Cloud database
WALLET_LOCATION = (SOURCE = (METHOD = file) (METHOD_DATA = (DIRECTORY="D:\cloudwallet")))
SSL_SERVER_DN_MATCH=yes
```

---

```
# tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File: 
C:\app\Learncode\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\tnsnames.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

LISTENER_ORCL =
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))

 ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
 (DESCRIPTION =
 (ADDRESS_LIST =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
   )
  (CONNECT_DATA =
    (SID = CLRExtProc)
    (PRESENTATION = RO)
   )
   )

   ORCL =
   (DESCRIPTION =
   (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
   (CONNECT_DATA =
   (SERVER = DEDICATED)
   (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)
    )
    )

   atpdb_high = (description= (retry_count=20)(retry_delay=3)(address=(protocol=tcps)(port=1522) ......)

   atpdb_low = (description= (retry_count=20)(retry_delay=3)(address=(protocol=tcps)(port=1522)......)

   atpdb_medium = (description= (retry_count=20)(retry_delay=3)(address=(protocol=tcps)(port=1522)......)

   atpdb_tp = (description= (retry_count=20)(retry_delay=3)(address=(protocol=tcps)(port=1522)......)

   atpdb_tpurgent = (description= (retry_count=20)(retry_delay=3)(address=(protocol=tcps)(port=1522)......)
```

---

And then i did tnsping atpdb_high its giving error TNS-12560: TNS: protocol adapter error.

The local one(ORCL) is working fine but the cloud is not working

[image]

Can anyone please help me on this?